# Parsing through many files and extract data to a new file?

Tags: file, pdf, text, new-operator, extract

Ok! My grey hairs have started popping out because of this.

I have 400 PDF files which I want to extract a line from. The line starts with DIR and then a number follows. But I will need the file name as well!

So do anyone know a way to parse through PDFs (or I can convert them to txt) and then search for a term, expand, append file name to it and save it into a new file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,

Tor

Comment: Did you tell you can convert PDF files to TXT? If so, post an example of that file and explain better what you need. We gonna help you

Comment: If you need to convert PDF files to TXT, you could try [this](http://www.somepdf.com/some-pdf-to-txt-converter.html): it seems to be free for 30 days...

Answer (score 0):

You have **Itext** library that you can use for opening the pdf.
Than you will need to scan each pdf for your pattern 
The link to the library www.itextpdf.com